# c++ Bridge pattern and smart pointer

Tags: c++, boost, vector, bridge

I use a bridge for one class, and I would life to create an std::vector of std::vector of the bridge.

Whilst the vector of bridge is working.

For example :

```
std::vector<Bridge> lBridge(5)
```

the vector of vector is not working.
For example :

```
std::vector<std::vector<Bridge>> lBridge(5,std::vector<Bridge>(4))
```

When I create the vector of vector, it goes to this constructor Bridge(const Bridge & original), and original is NULL...

This is my code :

Bridge.h

```
#ifndef BRIDGE_H
#define BRIDGE_H
#pragma once

#include <MyObject.h>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class Bridge{

public :

    Bridge(const Bridge & original);
    Bridge(const MyObject & innerObject);
    Bridge(){};
    Bridge& operator=(const IBridge& original);
private :
    boost::shared_ptr<MyObject> mMyObjectPtr;
};

#endif
```

Bridge.cpp

```
#include<Bridge.h>



Bridge::Bridge(constBridge& inOriginal){
    mMyObjectPtr = inOriginal.mMyObjectPtr->clone();
}

Bridge::Bridge(const MyObject& inInnerObject){
    mMyObjectPtr = inInnerObject.clone();
}

Bridge& Bridge::operator=(const Bridge& inOriginal){

    if (this != &inOriginal){
        mMyObjectPtr = inOriginal.mMyObjectPtr->clone();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a Question&Answers site. What is the question?

Comment: How are you actually accessing the `lBridge` vector of vectors?

Comment: I think that Bridge pattern is not related to the question

Comment: change your design, use pointers of Bridge object. std::vector<std::vector<Bridge*>> lBridge. Then use push_back(), pop_back(), etc to access vector and vector inside vector.

Answer (score 0):

You've failed to say what "not working" means as well as what you expected to happen.

My best guess is that you absolutely, positively, want all of the bridges to be default initialized, rather than what you've written, which is to *copy* a vector of bridges into each entry of the vector-of-vectors.

To do this, you'll have to make a vector of empty vectors, and then resize each of the individual vectors. Or alternatively, create an empty vector of vectors, then `emplace_back` the individual vectors one at a time.